# Box Shadow - remove fade in/out

Tags: html, css, sass, transition

The transition of the `box-shadow` makes fade in/out effect of the box shadow.
It is visible when you set a slow transition.

Is possible to remove this fade effect, that shadow appears only by x and y position?

Example: https://codepen.io/crowscript/pen/yLvpKNa

Comment: Do you mean you want the shadow to appear instantly without a transition? If so you can just remove `transition: box-shadow 2s ease-out;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the transition completely, you can delete this line:

```
transition:box-shadow 2s ease-out
```

Or if you want to keep the transition but have it fade-in in place, you need to set the shadow on the element then transition the colour:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: box-shadow 2s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 0 0 transparent;
}

a:hover {
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 0 0 #c00000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    Test link
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you pre-define the `box-shadow` on the initial element, it will not have the fade effect.  See my example:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: box-shadow 2s ease;
  box-shadow: .01rem .01rem 0 0 #c00000;
}

a:hover {
  box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 0 0 #c00000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">
      Test link
  </a>
</div>
```